# Capturing an offline NSView to an NSImage

Tags: cocoa, drawing, core-animation, calayer, nsview

I'm trying to make a custom animation for replacing an `NSView` with another.
For that reason I need to get an image of the `NSView` before it appears on the screen.

The view may contain layers and `NSOpenGLView` subviews, and therefore standard options like `initWithFocusedViewRect` and `bitmapImageRepForCachingDisplayInRect` do not work well in this case (they layers or OpenGL content well in my experiments).

I am looking for something like `CGWindowListCreateImage`, that is able to "capture" an offline `NSWindow` including layers and OpenGL content.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a category for this:

```
@implementation NSView (PecuniaAdditions)

/**
 * Returns an offscreen view containing all visual elements of this view for printing,
 * including CALayer content. Useful only for views that are layer-backed.
 */
- (NSView*)printViewForLayerBackedView;
{
    NSRect bounds = self.bounds;
    int bitmapBytesPerRow = 4 * bounds.size.width;

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateWithName(kCGColorSpaceSRGB);
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate (NULL,
                                                  bounds.size.width,
                                                  bounds.size.height,
                                                  8,
                                                  bitmapBytesPerRow,
                                                  colorSpace,
                                                  kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    if (context == NULL)
    {
        NSLog(@"getPrintViewForLayerBackedView: Failed to create context.");
        return nil;
    }

    [[self layer] renderInContext: context];
    CGImageRef img = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
    NSImage* image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithCGImage: img size: bounds.size];

    NSImageView* canvas = [[NSImageView alloc] initWithFrame: bounds];
    [canvas setImage: image];

    CFRelease(img);
    CFRelease(context);
    return canvas;
}

@end
```

This code is primarily for printing NSViews which contain layered child views. Might help you too.

Comment: This solution requires the NSOpenGLView subclass to be able to draw to a bitmap context, but besides that, it's fine.